# Return count from different arguments

Tags: sql, group-by, count

Let's say i have a table like this

```
ID NAME     DATE     STATUS 
1  FIRST  2021-01-01   1
1  SECOND 2021-01-02   1
1  THIRD  2021-01-01   0
1  FOURTH 2021-01-02   0
1  FIFTH  2021-01-02   1
```

and i want to return the count of total rows, plus a count from rows with a given status (lets say 1), all grouped by date.

So final result would be like :

```
CountRows CountStatus    Date
   2          1       2021-01-01
   3          2       2021-01-02
```

What's the logic and sintaxe for this query if it's possible.

Comment: GROUP BY date. For CountStatus, use a `case` expression to do _conditional aggregation_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If status can take on values other than `0` or `1`, you would want explicit logic:

```
select count(*), sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end), date
from t
group by date;
```

Comment: Yeah, this does the job because this way i can set the status i want to count in the case clause and add 1 by each. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can do aggregation :

```
select count(*) as countrows, sum(status) as countstatus, date
from t
group by date;
```

Comment: Yeah, but in this case it will only work with status 1 right? My example wasn't especific.